# Cannot Create New Group Policy Preferences

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, group-policy

In Group Policy Editor I cannot create new Group Policy Preference items in the Control Panel Settings (Data Sources to Start Menu in Group Policy Management Editor).

I was trying to create a file association (`Folder Options` > `Open With` but no dialog box appears when I click on this. Interestingly, it does appear with Printers and Internet Options.

I think that this information is contained with the file `C:\Windows\System32\gpprefcl.dll` as per the registry showing GPExtensions and this file definitely exists (albeit a different size/version to one on another server with the same OS). I have tried a few things including re-registering that .DLL but I'm not sure it's needed. RegDllView doesn't show this file as registered on either server (one that doesn't work, and one that does) despite the regsvr32 success message.

Screenshot of issue:
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just fixed this issue using Process Monitor. 
Filtered to Process Name mmc.exe and Operation to CreateFile and could see the failed capture referencing a file `C:\Windows\System32\propshts.dll` with the status 'NAME NOT FOUND' and this file didn't exist. The .mui equivalent did mind you. 
This file is the Group Policy Preferences Property Sheet and once I copied it in from another server, the properties dialog box appeared when I click on `Open With`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all is the GPO set under computer or user configuration ? Have your checked RSOP to see if the policy is applying with no errors ? Some GPP requires a machine reboot after gpupdate / force .

If the settings are under user configuration make sure you have group policy loopback procession mode is set to merge .

Comment: This is not client side. This is having created a new GPO on the server and it affects both User and Computer Configuration.

Comment: We might not be on the same side can you please post the configurations made in the GPO and maybe a screen shot .

Comment: Hi, I have not made any configuration changes in the GPO because I can't  (the dialog box for certain Control Panel items does not appear). Not sure how a screenshot will show this but I'll add one anyway.

Comment: Link in OP to screenshot. When I click on 'Open With' nothing happens.